# Как исправить ошибку в Json?

Tags: php, json

Есть такой JSON: [ссылка на визуальный редактор json](https://jsoneditoronline.org/#right=local.jodoku&left=cloud.54ecce839c5849259f42de0ec969437a)

Я хочу его разобрать средствами php, но в нем какая-то ошибка, и ничего не получается:

> Error: Parse error on line 1:
>   {'cpData':[{'TStatusI
>   -^
>   Expecting 'STRING', '}'

Почему возникает эта ошибка? Буду благодарен за помощь!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используй двойные кавычки

```
{
    "cpData": [
        {
            "TStatusId": "Адмиралтейский",
            "TStatus.Name": "Адмиралтейский"
        }
     ]
}
```

Comment: Действительно помогло! Спасибо) А существует ли какой-то способ который заменит одинарную ковычку на двойную? (можно было бы через str_replace , но что если в значении будет ковычка).

Comment: Не понял вопроса. json откуда появляется в php?